# select latest clicked in a list to have a certain property

Tags: jquery

I have video icons in a list, inside which I am adding some div as a popup, which i am toggling on click of each of these icons. I want the latest div popup to come on top of other previous shown divs.
the jquery i used is:

```
 $('.icon_videonew').each(function () {
       // alert('each');
        $(this).append('<div class="cam-poppupp" style="background: #ff0">something</div>');
        $(this).click(function () {
            $(this).children('.cam-poppupp').fadeToggle(80);
        });
    });
```

I want the latest div popup to have more z-index value than the previous divs that come as popup, so the z-index value for the previous popups(that were once latest) to go back to less z-index value. Please suggest some code

here is fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7b2hz5gw/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just have an incrementing z-index value:

```
var zIndex = 1;
$('.icon_videonew').each(function () {
   // alert('each');
    $(this).append('<div class="cam-poppupp" style="background: #ff0; z-index: ' + zIndex++ + ';">something</div>');
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).children('.cam-poppupp').fadeToggle(80);
    });
});
```

First appended `div` will get `z-index` 1, next 2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
  $(this).append('<div class="cam-poppupp" style="background: #ff0">something</div>');
        $(this).click(function () {

           //Reduce the z-index of all prev popups
            $('.cam-poppupp').css('zIndex', 99);           
            $(this).children('.cam-poppupp').css('zIndex', 100).fadeToggle(80);
        });
```

I am first reducing the z-Index of all the other popups and then, set the z-Index of the new popup to 100.

The updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7b2hz5gw/1/